# how to map nginx $request_uri parts into variables

Tags: regex, dictionary, nginx, request-uri

i found in [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/589222) who to map the first directory of $request_uri into a nginx variable.

I need to do it whit 2 directories and one file:  localhost:80/dir1/dir2/file.html map to localhost:80/$topdir/$secondir/$file

i do:

```
map $request_uri $topdir {
    ~(?<captured_topdir>[^\/]*[^\/]) $captured_topdir;
}
map $request_uri $secondir{
    ~([^\/]?<secondir>[^\/]) $secondir;
}
map $request_uri $endpart {
    ~([^\/]*[^\/]?<endpart>) $endpart;
}
```

but no luck at all, when i try it on nginx only $topdir is working right!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I finnaly solve this in a different way, whitout map. Just inside location i used

```
        if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)/(.*)/(.*).*$" ) {
            set  $first  $1;
            set  $second $2;
            set  $third $3;
        }
```

Then now, $first, $second and $third have each part.